# Converting vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, std-pair

I have a function `void process(int numSamples, double *const *arrayOfChannels)` for processing an audio stream (left and right channel samples).

Usually, the data for the second argument comes in the form `double* audioData[2]`.

Now, I would like to work with samples that are stored in a vector of pairs (`std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> audioData`).

What would be the best way to pass the vector to the function?

Comment: Since the memory layout is incompatible, there's no other way than actually converting to the other format.

Comment: If your function expects a jagged array of pointers then you'll have to create such an array to pass to the function, because the vector stores all the items contiguously. It might be better to change the function if you can

Comment: In other words, I will have to create an array of pointers having the correct size, loop over the entire vector and copy the elements, correct?. Or is there a more elegant way? Thank you in advance!